# Use table file (.tbl) to convert hex to string

Tags: c#, arrays, hex, binaryreader

I am currently reading the hex data from a nes rom (Zelda 2 to be specific). Normal hex editors use a table file to convert the hex into text because every rom uses the hex data different. Is there a native way to use this in my application? I am reading the nes rom like this:

```
  BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(@"C:\zelda2.nes", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None));
  reader.BaseStream.Position = 0x10;     
  byte[] data = reader.ReadBytes(0x30); 
  reader.Close();

  string str = Encoding.Default.GetString(data); 
  string hex = BitConverter.ToString(data);

  label1.Text = str;
  label2.Text = hex;
```

I am trying to make a "text editor" for Zelda 2, but of course the output is not the real text used in the game, because normally you would use a table file. The table file for Zelda 2 would look like this:

```
CE=/
CF=.
D0=0
D1=1
D2=2
D3=3
D4=4
D5=5
D6=6
D7=7
D8=8
D9=9
DA=A
DB=B
DC=C
DD=D
DE=E
DF=F
E0=G
E1=H
E2=I
E3=J
E4=K
E5=L
E6=M
E7=N
E8=O
E9=P
EA=Q
EB=R
EC=S
ED=T
EE=U
EF=V
F0=W
F1=X
F2=Y
F3=Z
F4= 
F5= 
F6=-
```